# Subtitue named variables with semicolon in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some strings with unusual named parameters with sql-code:

```
select :param1, :param2 from my_table
```

and dictionary:

```
{'param1': 'val1', 'param2': 'val2'}
```

I'm sending this for remote execution and I want to log request in executable form:

```
select val1, val2 from my_table
```

Is there a simple way to perform this substitution in Python 2.7?

Comment: can you clarify a little more? are you asking about how to get a value from a dictionary? or to substitute values in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the dictionary and replace the key with the value:

```
s = 'select :param1, :param2 from my_table'

d = {'param1': 'val1', 'param2': 'val2'}

for k, v in d.items():
    s = s.replace(':'+k, v)
```

In Python 2.7 you'll have to use `iteritems()` instead of `items()`.

Comment: Well, now I'm ashamed that I hadn't thought about it =) Thanks a lot!